# Is it true that there are phenomena without causes?

Tags: causality

assume that there is cause A for "existence of all causality"

(A -> all causality exist)

It is contradictory that cause A belonging to causality exists before all causality exists.

Thus, "all causality exist" have no causes.

is this true?

Comment: The "existence of all causality" is not a physical event. Only physical events have causes.

Comment: That A stands on the left side of A -> B does not mean that that the causation happens in time and A is "before" B. Indeed, something like "the cause of all causality" is very plausibly timeless, like God. This said, there may well be far less fanciful phenomena without causes, outcomes of quantum experiments, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Phenomena exists only in our heads. Outside of us, there's only fields, atoms, whatever, but there is no spoon, there's no kettle boiling, there's no sunny morning. And inside of our minds, facts have causes. We usually find causes for most things, but me might idealize random facts (like quantum mechanics facts), which have no apparent causes.

Causality is a rational mechanism, so it is subjective. Therefore, some facts might be ideally pure. This don't mean that physical facts are pure. In nature, everything is related with every other thing. But there's no noumenal causality. There's only phenomenal causality, the subjective interpretation of the world we humans experience.

Comment: +1 I like the direction of this. Causality is subjective because it is a limited representation crafted by the observer; but does that imply causality doesn't exist, or rather, causality exists in a way that an observer can only see a portion, much like the Jain monks who each had their part of the elephant?

Comment: I mean, strictly the phenomena are there, but the grouping or 'chunking' of them into typological groups is a mind-thing, eg a solar radiation flux not blocked by water vapour on land recently turned to the Sun, is fields + atoms terms